# Python GDAL installation by pip fails

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I tried to install python GDAL via pip but getting the following error:

```
extensions/gdal_wrap.cpp:4265:47: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GDALDatasetCreateLayer'; did you mean 'GDALDatasetShadow_CreateLayer'? OGRLayerShadow* layer = (OGRLayerShadow*) GDALDatasetCreateLayer( self, GDALDatasetShadow_CreateLayer
```

I guessed the reason is the mismatched version of GDAL library, so tried this:

```
$ brew unlink gdal
$ brew install gdal
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24
```

But, still getting the error.

Do I need to install an older version of python GDAL? If so, please let me know which version.

Thanks.

Comment: Pip and GDAL are notorious for failing to work together. Have you tried the [OsX GDAL port by Kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks)?

Comment: Nor have you made clear which gdalinfo you are running nor what its library dependencies are.  Try `otool -L $(which gdalinfo)` as well as just `which gdalinfo` to be sure. If you tried installing via pip, did you use the system's python / pip or did you use brew's? Are you perhaps still using the former? Are you using a virtualenv for any of this?

Answer (score 10):

As of today, brew has

`gdalinfo --version
GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10`

Thus, 
`pip install GDAL==1.11.2`

Goes just fine. Pypi has 2.0.0 available

Comment: I found that you do not need the exact same version (it failed to install too), but the same major version.